# Can resizing image give different image to world co-ordinate transformation?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, blender, camera-calibration, coordinate-transformation

This may seem stupid but the more I read about camera-image-world co-ordinate systems and their intermediate conversions the more I am confused.

I am using depth maps synthetically generated using Blender 2.78 and using them for processing. This also involves cropping and resizing the images. I have my camera matrix (intrinsic, extrinsic parameters) and also matrix for perspective projection.

I am detecting some keypoints in these cropped, resized images and trying to get the world co-ordinates of these keypoints. If I am not wrong, the keypoints are defined in image co-ordinate system. But due to cropping they have different locations as opposed to the original image that I generated using Blender.

Will using the camera matrices to convert these keypoint co-ordinates into world coordinates give me the accurate world co-ordinates? Is there a way to verify whether these are the actual world co-ordinates of these image keypoints?

**EDIT**

Original image rendered using blender with resolution 960x540:

[image]

Image after pre-processing, cropping and resizing with detected SIFT keypoints (resolution 250x200):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you'll have to adjust the camera intrinsics, since the principal point and pixel-size have changed. OR you just change the keypoint locations by the inverse resize/cropping operation!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using openCV+python for my processing. When you say change the camera intrinsics, does it mean use something like [`cv2.calibrateCamera`](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html)? Also if could explain a bit more what exactly do you mean by inverse resize and cropping it would be very helpful! For my project I need to get some specific ROI only for further steps in pipeline and hence I **have to** do the resizing and cropping of the images.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I can get the object points from blender itself with fixed camera position. I have the image points i.e. keypoints' co-ordinates from the image. But I won't have the correspondencies between them. Right? And to get the camera intrinsics I need these to solve using function described in above comment.

Comment: if you want to use your original image to world functions with the camera intrinsics and extrinsics of your original image, you have to know the keypoint positions in your original image. If you scaled your image by factor 0.5 you have to multiply your keypoint position by 2. If you removed L pixel from left border and T pixel from top border you have to add L to x and T to y coordinate of that point. Best would be if you add some sample images and keypoints

Comment: you should provide the ROI and resizing information or the new camera intrinsics to your pipeline module that performs the keypoints2world stuff

Comment: I have added some images for reference. After this step I have some matching to do with template image and also classification. But thanks to you and your inputs @Micka now atleast I am sure that the camera intrinsics do have to change which was my original confusion. I will try out what you said and see where I go. :)

Comment: Just in addition to Micka's answer: There exist methods for pose determination of a partially calibrated camera. Here one for varying focal length http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Zheng_A_General_and_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf